# What is the difference between 'being competent' and 'being skilled'?

Tags: differences

Is there any distinctive difference between **being skilled** and **being competent**?

Comment: "Competent" is often used in a sense of "not the most-skilled person in the shop, but pretty good most of the time".

Comment: You pretty much have to have *some* skills to be deemed competent in most domains. Even trash-haulers need to know how to drive without scraping the sides off of parked cars.

Comment: @Robusto - Or at least how to drive away quickly, before anyone notices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Competent](https://www.lexico.com/definition/competent):** Having the necessary ability, knowledge, or skill to do something successfully.

**[Skilled](https://www.lexico.com/definition/skilled):**
Having or showing the knowledge, ability, or training to perform a certain activity or task well.

> **Difference between skill and competence (or skilled and competent):**
>
> A major difference between skills and competencies is one of scope.  Competencies are much broader than skills.  Skills are specific to a task, while competencies incorporate a set of skills with abilities and knowledge.  Skills are just one of three facets that make up a competency; the other two are knowledge and abilities.
>
> Additionally, learning a new skill is typically quicker than learning a competency.  You can learn a skill in a relatively short training class, however, a person develops competencies over time through practice and experience.
>
> In business, competencies are the effective application of a combination of skills.  Organizations create competencies by translating specific skills into on-the-job behaviors that demonstrate the ability to perform the job requirements successfully.  Competencies are also used to define the requirements for success on the job in broader terms than skills do. (Reference:
> [The Peak performance centre](https://thepeakperformancecenter.com/business/learning/course-design/learning-goals-objectives-outcomes/difference-between-competencies-and-skills/amp/))

---

> **Difference between skill and competence:**
>
> Skills are the specific learned abilities that you need to perform a given job well. Examples, depending on the specific role, range from handling accounts and coding to welding or writing tenders. There is a distinction, however, to be made between hard skills and soft skills. Whereas a hard skill is a technical and quantifiable skill that a professional may demonstrate through their specific qualifications and professional experiences, a soft skill is a non-technical skill that is less rooted in specific vocations. An example of a hard skill, then, may be computer programming or proficiency in a foreign language, whereas a soft skill may be time management or verbal communication. Competencies, on the other hand, are the person’s knowledge and behaviours that lead them to be successful in a job. Examples of competencies, then, include the improvement of business processes, strategic planning and data-based decisions. Competencies effectively explain how an individual’s behaviours bring about the desired results in their role. As with skills, there are various types of competencies – including core competencies, which are those that any successful employee requires to rise through an organisation. In the words of marketer Aja Davis Isble, “…a core competency is something that is core to you and how you work – so it is something that could potentially set you apart from every other candidate.” (from [Hays](https://social.hays.com/2019/10/04/skills-competencies-whats-the-difference/))

Answer (score 0):

Being competent means to be having suitable and sufficient skill, knowledge, experience for some purpose.....it means to be properly qualified.

example: He is perfectly *competent* to manage the bank branch.

Being skilled is a well learned talent like being able to ride a bike, spin a basket ball on your fingers etc. Being skilled in something usually requires practice.If you have *skills*, you are *skilled*.

example: I am an analyst and a *skilled* technician.

```
       Hope it helps
```